# How can I change the Mouse Cursor over a Button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm currently Implementing Caliburn and having a mouseover implementation. I'm wondering how do I change the mouse cursor to the mouse on button.

Xaml Side:

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseOver] = [ChangeIcon]" />
```

Comment: maybe a style trigger

Comment: use css

     button {
     cursor: pointer;
     } see here http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3788/default-cursor-on-mouse-over-of-a-button-is-not-a-hand-pointer or use <Button x:Name="NextButton">
    <Button.Style>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
             <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow"/>
             or
             <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Wait"/>
         </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do not need to create a event handler for this. Just add to the `Style` of your *`Button`* this trigger:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Wait" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Besides, the Cursor and the Mouse event is related to a `View`. This means that it is desirable to do this action in not the `ViewModel`, and do it on the side of `View`.

Comment: Love it nice solution ! Lets UI stays in XAML.

Comment: better than what I suggested. Learn something new every day! I'll be using this myself. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

To change the cursor, you can use `Mouse.OverrideCursor Property`

```
private void CursorTypeChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
}
```

Then to reset, you can use :

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
```

another example (from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.overridecursor.aspx))

```
// Determines the scope the new cursor will have. 
// 
// If the RadioButton rbScopeElement is selected, then the cursor 
// will only change on the display element. 
//  
// If the Radiobutton rbScopeApplication is selected, then the cursor 
// will be changed for the entire application 
// 
private void CursorScopeSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton source = e.Source as RadioButton;

    if (source != null)
    {
        if (source.Name == "rbScopeElement")
        {
            // Setting the element only scope flag to true
            cursorScopeElementOnly = true;

            // Clearing out the OverrideCursor.  
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
        }
        if (source.Name == "rbScopeApplication")
        {
           // Setting the element only scope flag to false
           cursorScopeElementOnly = false;

           // Forcing the cursor for all elements. 
           Mouse.OverrideCursor = DisplayArea.Cursor;
        }
    }
}
```

Need more info ?

- List of properties of cursor class : [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.cursors.aspx)
- There is a great "How to" on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742195.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Mouse.OverrideCursor anywhere otherwise Cursor="Hand" will not work.

Instead when loading your App call this :

`Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;`

and everywhere call this :

`<Button Cursor="Hand"/>`

Using Mouse.OverrideCursor will set the cursor for entire App Space!

Answer (score 1):

In xaml try

```
<Button x:Name="btn" MouseEnter="btn_OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="btn_OnMouseLeave" />
```

in code behind

```
private void btn_OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // example. you can change to a specific type in the Cursors static class
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
}

private void btn_OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
}
```